# Delay in Jython script

Tags: loops, timer, delay, jython, sleep

My python script is told:

```
import time

def wait_seconds(x):
    print "started"
    time.sleep(x)
    print "stopped"
```

then when I tell it:

```
>>> wait(.2)
```

I get:

```
///it waits .2 seconds and then...
started
stopped
```

It waits before it does anything else and that is not what I am looking for.
if I use sleep in a loop it doesn't do anything (it's caught up doing the sleeping only)

Is there a better way to do short delays?
Thanks to anyone who replies! :D

Comment: For further information: I'm using this for a continuous game loop ;)

Answer (score 1):

Try flushing stdout before the delay.

Comment: This didn't seem to do anything. The problem seems to be lying in some kind of internal delay in either the function call or print call within Jython. In python it works perfectly, but in Jython there is a delay when the function is called which makes it appear that the sleep is being called first. If I increased the wait time to 5 seconds, there is a short delay, then "started" is printed, then the 5 second wait, then "stopped". I'm not familiar enough with Jython to be able to indicate what causes this delay.

Comment: Works fine here in Jython 2.2.1. Maybe you should describe your environment in more detail.

Comment: Well, I have seen people use ActionListener and Timer, however I am unclear on that as well (in Jython). I have used it in Java, though this is slightly different. This is my issue, different approaches exist, but I can't grasp any of them. :C thankyou for your reply tho :D

Comment: Works fine on WinXP with Jython 2.5.2 and Java 1.7.0_05